# ubuntu button missing on desktop

Tags: 12.04, button

I installed ubuntu 12.04 from scratch and I'm missing the ubuntu button , so I can not go into system -> users and groups for instance.

What could be the problem. I installed it on 2 netbooks , and they both share the same problem.

Kind regards ,

Ronny

Comment: Can you add a link to the screenshots of the exact thing?

Comment: thansk , but how can I for example goto users and groups ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no menu button anymore in 12.04, just the Unity launcher.

To access settings you would press the Meta key(Windows key) and start to type "system" and you should see the "System Settings" shortcut appear.

[image]